# Given a unitary matrix, how do I show two of its components are unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a unitary block matrix $A$.

$$A : = \begin{pmatrix}P &R \\
O & Q
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Given that $P_{m,m}$, $Q_{n,n}$  how do I show that P and Q are unitary and R = O ?.

where matrix $P_{n,m}$, $Q_{n×n}$. Show that $P$ and $Q$ are unitary matrices and $R$ = $O$.

My first attempt is using $A^*A$ = $I_{m+n}$ which leaves me with the equations:

1) $P^*P + O^*O = I$

2) $P^*R + O^*Q = 0$

3) $R^*P + Q^*O = 0$

4) $R^*R + Q^*Q = I$

How do I proceed?

Comment: I think you may have misread the question.  I think $O$ is meant to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} Verify yourself this is unitary. What is your $P$ and $Q$ here? Are they unitary?. Now assume $R$ and $O$ were zero matrices. Now try proceeding your way.